# mysql: show two separate fields become one field

Tags: mysql, field

dear all..i have a table it looks like:

```
Name        version
DDX           01
DTX           05
```

could i combine two separate fields become one field? and it will show like:

```
Model
DDX01
DTX05
```

thanks before..

Comment: Do you want to change your table structure or combine the columns in a query?

Comment: i want combine the columns in a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following query (using [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)) to insert the Model in a new table or a new column

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(Name,version) AS Model
FROM
  table
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) keyword. As for your question, it will be like:-

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name, version) AS Model FROM table
```

(as mentioned by others already)

Hope it helps.